# A value of type 'Products' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Products>'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<List<Products>> getApiData() async {
    var url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonString = response.body;
    List<Products> products = productsFromJson(jsonString);
    
    print(jsonString);
    return products;   
    
  }
```

why it doesn't work,
[A value of type 'Products' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.;][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQCEP.png
```

***json to dart file***
***A value of type 'Products' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
Try changing the type of the variable,dart(invalid_assignment)***

```
Products productsFromJson(String str) => 
Products.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String productsToJson(Products data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class Products {
  Products({
    this.code,
    this.meta,
    this.data,
  });
  int code;
  Meta meta;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Products(
        code: json["code"],
        meta: Meta.fromJson(json["meta"]),
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "code": code,
        "meta": meta.toJson(),
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}
class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.image,
    this.price,
    this.discountAmount,
    this.status,
    this.categories,
  });
  int id;
  String name;
  String description;
  String image;
  String price;
  String discountAmount;
  bool status;
  List<Category> categories;
```

Comment: productsFromJson is returning a Products object, not a List<Products>. Change it to Products products = productsFromJson(jsonString); and see if it works

Comment: What is the implementation of the productsFromJson() function?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], we have no way of knowing, what `productsFromJson` may do or return or where the mistake lies.

Comment: "class Products" is a bad name for this class.  It's a single Product, not many Products.  That inevitably leads to other errors later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products";
var response = await http.get(url);
var jsonString = jsonDecode(response.body);
List<Products> products = jsonString.map((jsonMap) => Products.fromJson(jsonMap)).toList();
```

If you need to return all products as list, you can use like this.

Answer (score 0):

You created a Modle class for Products, so **productsFromJson(jsonString)** return a Products response.
but you try to put the API response to List variable, and then it causes an error.

change your API call by below code it will work fine.

```
Future<Products> getApiData() async {
    var url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonString = response.body;
    Products products = productsFromJson(jsonString);
    
    print(jsonString);
    return products;   
    
}
```

Comment: @SudarshanaAtapattu great :)  btw in stackoverflow we give thanks by accepting answer and upvoting